# Bidimensional array input

Tags: java, arrays

I have a homework were the user have to input 10 word inside an array, but i cant find a way to do that

like for example if the user input this words:

```
 abigail
 wilbert
 steve
 android
 lucky
 hello
 help
 htc
 matrix
 kim
```

the output should be when i print the array

```
abigail
 wilbert
 steve
 android
 lucky
 hello
 help
 htc
 matrix
  kim
```

this my program

```
import java.io.*;
class example
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    matrix obj=new matrix();
    obj.practice();
}
}
class matrix
{
void practice() throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    char A[][]=new char[10][10];
    int r,c,i,j;
    String x;
    char b;
    for(r=0;r<10;r++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the "+(r+1)+" word");
        x=br.readLine();
        for(c=0;c<x.length();c++)
        {
            A[r][c]=x.charAt(c);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
                System.out.print(A[i][j]);
        }
    }   System.out.print("\n");


}
```

}

Comment: Where are you stuck? What does your program do so far?

Comment: i only want to get inside the array the word that the user input im a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your are using a multi-dimensional array.  Here is a solution that will work for you that demonstrates some OO concepts.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StringArrayOfWords {

  //instance variables
  private ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
  private static StringArrayOfWords arr = new StringArrayOfWords();//declare object

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String [] printArray = arr.readFile();//use an array to hold contents of arr.readFile for easy printing
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(printArray));//Arrays.toString will print the contents of an Array
    }

    //method to read a file and call on object 
    public String [] readFile() throws Exception{  
        //display a gui window to choose a file to read in
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a question file");        
        JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
        int a = input.showOpenDialog(null);
        String file = "";
        if (a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = input.getSelectedFile();
            file = selectedFile.getPath();
        }

        //use file input to read in line one at a time
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        //convert ArrayList to array
        String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use array because is a homework, i cant add things to the program if the teacher havent teach it yet

Comment: There is a distinction between an "array" and a "multi-dimensional" array.  You are using a multidimensional array but specifying that you need to use an array, which is very confusing.  Beyond clarifying your question you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for info on the appropriate way to ask questions.  I realize that you are just starting out but it is important to do your research before "giving in" and asking a question here.  That being said, the above program should give you a good idea how to read in text from input and store the info in an array.  Good luck!